# Is it possible to update a single page using WP-CLI?

Tags: wp-cli

I'm currently working on a website which is based on Wordpress. It's not that usual Wordpress blog which is using posts but rather a non-profit association website. Once a week a single page need to be updated with new content (text + audio file).

I'd like to do that via bash scripts using WP-CLI. However, I found no way to update a specific Wordpress page with WP-CLI. Is it possible to update a single Wordpress page via WP-CLI?

If not, maybe that's the wrong approach and I should use the blog functionality of Wordpress. How is it possible to create a post which includes an audio file via WP-CLI?

Answer (score 0):

You can update posts using [wp update](https://wp-cli.org/commands/post/update/)
But you probably want a to create custom [package](https://wp-cli.org/commands/package/) to do exactly what you want. Also see [Commands Cookbook](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/commands-cookbook/)